# UNET - Object is synced over network but text component isn't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi so I'm trying to make chat for a multiplayer game and I've gotten the message prefabs to instantiate on all clients and the host, so that works fine. Only issue is the text doesnt change, it stays as the default. Here is the code I have:

ChatManager.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ChatManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject chat;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject chatItemPrefab;
    [HideInInspector] public List<ChatItem> messages;

    public float messageExpireTime = 5;

    public static ChatManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void ChatSendMessage(string sender, string message)
    {
        CmdChatSendMessage(sender, message);
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdChatSendMessage(string sender, string message)
    {
        GameObject chatItem = Instantiate(chatItemPrefab);
        chatItem.transform.SetParent(chat.transform);
        ChatItem messageSettings = chatItem.GetComponent<ChatItem>();
        messageSettings.Setup(sender, message);
        messageSettings.chatNetId = chat.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().netId;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(chatItem);
        StartCoroutine(WaitForExpire(chatItem));
    }

    public IEnumerator WaitForExpire(GameObject chatItem)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(messageExpireTime);
        CmdDestroyChatMessage(chatItem);
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdDestroyChatMessage(GameObject chatItem)
    {
        NetworkServer.Destroy(chatItem);
    }
}
```

ChatItem.cs:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ChatItem : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text senderText;
    [SerializeField] private Text messageText;
    [SyncVar] public NetworkInstanceId chatNetId;

    [SyncVar] public string sender;
    [SyncVar] public string message;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject chatParent = ClientScene.FindLocalObject(chatNetId);
        transform.SetParent(chatParent.transform);
    }

    public void Setup(string sender, string message)
    {
        senderText.text = string.Format("[{0}]:", sender);
        messageText.text = message;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

If "ChatSendMessage" is called with the paremeters "Server" and "hello!" on the host:

The host sees:

[image: Host]

But the client sees:

[image: Client]

which is the default text..

What is the issue I'm dealing with. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FIXED - I set the text in the start method as well so if you're the person sending, it gets overwritten by the setup method but if you're a remote client, where setup is never run, you can just set the text from the syncvar which was already set from the setup method on the person sending's client. e.g.

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject chatParent = ClientScene.FindLocalObject(chatNetId);
    transform.SetParent(chatParent.transform);
    senderText.text = string.Format("[{0}]:", sender);
    messageText.text = message;
}
```